# How to extract all numbers not in quotation marks using regex?

Tags: c#, regex

I need to extract all numbers in string which are NOT in quotation marks and are NOT the part of variable name.

In Example, I have this code:

```
const VariableA1 = '5;0;5;5;0;5;3;3;7;7';
const M65 = true;

type MyType = record
    H: array[0..27] of integer;
    S: integer;
end;

function B(sep: Char) : integer;
var i: integer;
begin
    i:= 1;
    return sep[0];
end;
```

I resolved it myself, here is the code:

```
(?<![a-zA-Z])[0-9]+(?=([^']*'[^']*')*[^']*$)
```

but regex101 throwing timeout error - catastrophic backtracking.
Evaluation of this pattern is 8 seconds long.

Is there way to this better? Can you help me optimize this pattern?

Comment: Maybe you can explain a little more what your solution is doing? :)

Comment: I need to create obfuscator for pascal like scripts.

Comment: What is the programming language you are using? It is impossible to optimize a regex without knowing what engine it uses.

Comment: @stribizhev  I'm using C# to obfuscate pascal code.

Comment: I suggest a 2-way approach: remove all quoted strings (use `txt = Regex.Replace(txt, "'[^']*'", "")`) and then get all the whole numbers using `Regex.Matches(txt, @"\b\d+\b")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\b[0-9]+(?=(?:[^']*'[^']*')*[^']*$)
```

You can simply use this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/gT6vU5/4

For Faster approach you can use

```
\b[0-9]+(?=(?>(?:[^']*'[^']*')*)[^']*$)

           ^^
```

Make use of atomic groups.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/gT6vU5/6

EDIT:

if you are sure that quotes dont span multiple lines you can use

```
\b[0-9]+(?![^\n]*')
```

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/gT6vU5/5

Comment: My file is 1000 line length, this is faster solution indeed, but still evaluated time is longer than 2sec

Comment: @vks: your update is even slower :) Check it at [regexhero](http://regexhero.net/tester).

Comment: @vks regex101.com/r/gT6vU5/5 this is really nice solution and works 10 times faster! I think this solution is enough for my needs :) Please inlcude this solution in your answer.

Comment: `\b[0-9]+(?![^\n]*')` is not safe since it will fail to extract a number from `i:= 1; s:='5,6,7';`.

Comment: @stribizhev i have checked at regexhero and it is `52` % faster.I have included large datasets.Logically too it should be super fast

Comment: @vks: My test says the atomic group in your regex slows the whole search down 8%. I'd go with a 2-step solution here.

Comment: @stribizhev even in regex101.com you can check the number of steps....it takes 4 times more steps in case of non atomic

Comment: @vks: I do not know why there is the discrepancy between your benchmark and mine. I'd just leave the choice to OP here.

Comment: No need to check that site since it does not support .NET regex. If I were to test, I'd create a program in C#.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this:

```
\*{1,}\d+\*{1,}
```

Comment: Asterisks should bold the numbers I need to extract, but its not work. I need to extract numbers. I modified my question.